# Using rank within a subgroup in HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Hey there I am trying to get this query to work using `rank()` but am having no luck,

```
select t.orig, t.id, count(*) as num_actions, 
rank() over (partition by t.orig order by count(*) desc) as rank
from sample_table t
where rank < 21 
and t.month in (201607,20608,201609,201610,201611,201612) 
and t.orig in (select tw.pageid from tw_sample as tw limit 50) 
group by t.orig, t.id
```

I keep getting,

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 4:6 Invalid table alias or column reference 'rank'

My goal is to grab the top 20 rows for each `t.orig` based on the `count(*)` parameter.

If you could also explain where I went wrong so I may learn from this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an alias in the `where` clause.  Use a subquery:

```
select *
from (select t.orig, t.id, count(*) as num_actions, 
             rank() over (partition by t.orig order by count(*) desc) as rnk
      from sample_table t
      where t.month in (201607, 20608, 201609, 201610, 201611, 201612)  and
            t.orig in (select tw.pageid from tw_sample tw limit 50) 
      group by t.orig, t.id
     ) t
where rank < 21
```